# How to execute a ffmpeg code on a GPU without using the command line?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, gpu

We have written a short code in C code to read a video file, using common libraries as `libavcodec`, `libavformat`, etc.

The code is running smoothly but only using the CPU resources. We'd need to run the code on the GPU (Nvidia GeForce 940MX and 1080Ti). Is there a way to force the code to be run on the GPU?

While using the command line (e.g., `ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -i vid.mp4 out.avi`) things are fine, we are not able to have it working on the GPU from the source code.

We are working with Ubuntu 18.04, and ffmpeg correctly compiled with CUDA 9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pretty good examples for using libav (ffmpeg) for encoding and decoding video at https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/tree/master/doc/examples.

For what you need is `demuxing_decoding.c` example and change the lines `166` which is:

```
/* find decoder for the stream */
dec = avcodec_find_decoder(st->codecpar->codec_id);
```

with

```
/* find decoder for the stream */
if (st->codecpar->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
{
    dec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("h264_cuvid");
}
else if (st->codecpar->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_HEVC)
{
    dec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("hevc_cuvid");
}
else
{
    dec = avcodec_find_decoder(st->codecpar->codec_id);
}
```

add/change lines for other formats. And make sure your FFmpeg compiled with `--enable-cuda --enable-cuvid`

In my tests I got error comes from line 85: because nvdec (hevc_cuvid) uses p010 internal format for 10bit (input is yuv420p10). Which means decoded frame will be either `NV12` pixel format or `P010` depending on bit depth. I hope you are familiar with pixel formats.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, our ffmpeg is correctly compiled with --enable-cuda and --enable-cuvid. We took a look to the file you linked but are you sure that is it sufficient to be able to run our code on the GPU?

Comment: According to what you said: *"While using the command line (e.g., ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -i vid.mp4 out.avi) things are fine"*. Yes it should work similar to command line version after some configuration. I see you actually output avi so you may also consider transcoding example on same web page, that will show you how to re-encode for desired format.

Comment: Ok.. We tried to add in the code the function avcodec_find_decoder_by_name() but it's still doesn't work on the GPU... We think we need to add something else in code that expilcitly force the code to be run by the GPU

Comment: I just tested the code with `hevc_cuvid` and an mp4 hevc video file. It definitely works on GPU because of I getting errors like "[hevc_cuvid @ 0x232bf00] Invalid NAL unit 62, skipping. [hevc_cuvid @ 0x232bf00] No start code is found." I realized this also means this example looks for un-muxed video stream. This is why it uses `fread` and practically useless. `demuxing_decoding.c` example uses `av_read_frame` which will do the job as its name (demuxing) also suggest. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: Yes it works!! Thank you so much!! We run the code on a GPU (GeForce 1080Ti) that supports both h264_cuvid and hevc_cuvid. We had had some issues beacuse the GPU that is mounted on our PC (GeForce 940MX) does not support h264_cuvid. Which GPU did you use to execute the code?

Comment: Non-Ti GTX 1080 8GB. Btw you still didn't choose the answer as accepted.

Comment: OK! It is accepted now! Sorry but it is my first post on stack overflow!